# How to restore "app.config" and "_.csproj" files after "File.Delete()" command?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, app-config, delete-file, csproj

Coding in C# using Visual Studio 2013,

My program accidentally deleted:

```
app.config
projectName.csproj
```

Now, I cannot run the program.
Any ideas how to fix the damage?

Comment: @SonerGönül i'm not sure this an exact duplicate. OP does not ask how to "undelete" the files, but a way to recreate app.config and .csproj files...

Comment: Is there a way to recreate the files ?

Comment: @Pikoh "How to restore “app.config” and “.csproj” files..." does _not_ mean "recreating" as far as I know. You can vote it for reopen if you disagree.

Comment: @SonerGönül well, the title may be misleading, but i think that's what op meant :)

Comment: @SonerGönül, Pikoh is correct. I'm interested in reconstructing the files.

Comment: @Tango_Chaser i think the easiest way to recreate csproj file is creating a new project and add your class files, references,etc.. to it. If it's not a big project it shouldn't be a lot of work

Comment: @Pikoh Thanks you.